# Trying to map a sphere with Perlin Noise

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So as the title says I'm trying to map properly a octahedron sphere using a 3D Perlin Noise as a procedural texture.

I suppose it has something to do about the UVs or about the edges vertices of the texture (left, right, probably even top and down). It's a texture with size 512*512, but it can be 1024*1024.

I've been documentating, trying other techniques, using normal maps, tangets, etc but i still can't figure out how to solve that seam (keep in mind it should be procedurally generated) to generate a surface around the sphere to update it during runtime (in that way I can change the noise (shape of the terrain) as well as the colours).

By the way, when I do the same with a prepared texture (1024*512) with the edges properly corrected the seam disappear, but what I want is the ability to change it in run time (can survive without it but would be nice to have it)

```css
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        if(autoUpdateTexture)
        {
            if (texture == null)
            {
                texture = new Texture2D(resolution, resolution, TextureFormat.RGB24, true);
                texture.name = "Procedural Texture";
                texture.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Repeat;
                texture.filterMode = FilterMode.Trilinear;
                texture.anisoLevel = 9;
 
                GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial.mainTexture = texture;
            }
 
            FillTexture();
        }
    }
 
    public void FillTexture()
    {
        if (texture.width != resolution)
        {
            texture.Resize(resolution, resolution);
        }
 
        Vector3 point00 = transform.TransformPoint(new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f));
        Vector3 point10 = transform.TransformPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f));
        Vector3 point01 = transform.TransformPoint(new Vector3(-0.5f, 0.5f));
        Vector3 point11 = transform.TransformPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f));
 
        NoiseMethod method = Noise.noiseMethods[(int)type][dimensions - 1];
        float stepSize = 1f / resolution;
        for (int y = 0; y < resolution; y++)
        {
            Vector3 point0 = Vector3.Lerp(point00, point01, (y + 0.5f) * stepSize);
            Vector3 point1 = Vector3.Lerp(point10, point11, (y + 0.5f) * stepSize);
            for (int x = 0; x < resolution; x++)
            {
                Vector3 point = Vector3.Lerp(point0, point1, (x + 0.5f) * stepSize);
                float sample = Noise.Sum(method, point, frequency, octaves, lacunarity, persistence);
                if (type != NoiseMethodType.Value)
                {
                    sample = sample * 0.5f + 0.5f;
                }
                texture.SetPixel(x, y, coloring.Evaluate(sample));
            }
        }
 
        texture.Apply();
    }
```

So, I  have 2 images, one showing the 3D generated noise in the sphere (when I save the textue to png it just goes to 2D, something obvious)
And the other one, showing that 3D noise IN the sphere with a seam at the edges, so the thing is get that 3D noise in the sphere without the seam.
If you need any more related info, please let me know, as this is giving me a nice headache.
[procedural texture in 2D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTDti.png)
[3D noise on sphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUIsn.png)

Comment: Use a seamless texture?

Comment: Well, is a procedural texture, and more, is supposed to be a 3D noise so the seam shouldnßt appear at all. the thing is not to use a seamless texture (that ofc will work) but you loose the advantages of the procedural texture,

Comment: 3D noise does not insure seamlessness. You need to map your coordinates so that the left and right edge use the same input values to the noise function.

Comment: @MateoPérezMurillo [Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZI1dmHv3MeM) a pretty good example of what you should be trying to do, it's the same idea in 3D.